# How store Timeout object in telegram-node-bot to start and stop timer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, telegram

So, I want implement timer in Telegram bot. A know how to start it, but I can't find a way to stop it by command. Here is a code

```
class TimerController extends TelegramBaseController {
  startTimer($) {
    let timer = setInterval(function () {
      $.sendMessage('Minute passed')
    }, 60000)
    $.setChatSession('timer', timer)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('stored')
    })
    .catch(reason => {
      console.log(reason)
    })
  }
  stopTimer($) {
    $.getChatSession('timer')
      .then(timer => {
        clearInterval(timer)
      })
      .catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason)
      })
  }
  get routes() {
    return {
      'timerCommand': 'startTimer',
      'stopTimerCommand': 'stopTimer',
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't work because Timeout object cannot be stringified. So I have no way to store information about active timers between handlers.

Comment: I tried use external variable, but there's 8 parallel Telegram Workers, and there's no guarantee, that stopTimer and startTimer handlers will be in same process.

Answer (score 0):

I found this workaround myself, not sure it's good enough. Now timer watch session and wait for command to stop.

```
class TimerController extends TelegramBaseController {
  startTimer($) {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.getChatSession('timerStop')
        .then((timerStop) => {
            if (timerStop === true) {
                console.log('stoping timer')
                clearInterval(this)
            } else {
                $.sendMessage('Minute passed')      
            }
        })
        .catch(reason => {
            console.log(reason)
        })
    }, 60000)
    $.setChatSession('timerStop', false)
    .then(() => {
        console.log('timer started')
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason)
    })
  }
  stopTimer($) {
    $.setChatSession('timerStop', true)
    .then( () => {
        console.log('ordering to stop timer')
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason)
    })
  }
  get routes() {
    return {
        'timerCommand': 'startTimer',
        'stopTimerCommand': 'stopTimer',
    }
  }
}
```